# When writing in Python a dictionary to a YAML file, how to make sure the string in the YAML file is split based on '\n'?

Tags: python, yaml

I have a long string in a dictionary which I will dump to a YAML file.

As an example

```
d = {'test': {'long_string':'this is a long string that does not succesfully split when it sees the character '\n' which is an issue'}}
ff = open('./test.yaml', 'w+')
yaml.safe_dump(d, ff)
```

Which produces the following output in the YAML file

```
 test:
      long_string: "this is a long string that does not successfully split when it sees\
\ the character '\n' which is an issue"
```

I want the string which is inside the YAML file to only be split into a new line when it sees the "\n", also, I don't want any characters indicating that it's a newline. I want the output as follows:

```
 test:
      long_string: "this is a long string that does not successfully split when it sees the character '' 
                    which is an issue"
```

What do I need to do to make the `yaml.dump` or `yaml.safe_dump` fulfill this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no general solution. YAML is a format intentionally designed in a way that lets the implementation decide on the exact representation of values.

What you can do is to *suggest* a format. The dumper will honor this suggestion if possible. The one scalar format that breaks at literal newlines in the value and nowhere else is a literal block scalar. This code will dump your string as such if possible:

```py
import yaml, sys

class as_block(str):
    @staticmethod
    def represent(dumper, data):
        return dumper.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data, style='|')

yaml.SafeDumper.add_representer(as_block, as_block.represent)

d = {'test': {'long_string':as_block('this is a long string that does not succes
fully split when it sees the character\n which is an issue')}}
yaml.safe_dump(d, sys.stdout)
```

Output:

```yaml
test:
  long_string: |-
    this is a long string that does not succesfully split when it sees the character
     which is an issue
```

I use `as_block` for the string that should be written as block scalar.
You can theoretically use this for all strings, but be aware that `long_string` and `test` would then also be written als block scalars, which is most probably not what you want.

This will not work when there is space before the line break, because YAML ignores space at the end of a line of a block scalar, so the serializer will choose another format to not lose the space character(s).

You can also take a step back and ask yourself why this is an issue in the first place. A YAML implementation is perfectly able to load the generated YAML and reconstruct your string.